# How do I pass ssh credentials to aws cdk deploy?

Tags: git, docker, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to have a private git repo in my requirements.txt file. As it is private, it looks as though I need to provide a username in the requirements file. Whenever I try to deploy though, it fails to get the repo because the Host key verification failed and it can't read from the repo.

Any idea how to pass through a ssh credentials file or some other way to access the repo with the docker container?

Comment: I do not think ssh is the right way to go here. You should idealy look into github oauth tokens and store it in secrets manager and pass them to the docker environment through secrets manager's reference.